# How can I pg_dump each table in its own file, and stay consistent?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a database with several tables, let's say `table_a` and `table_b`.

I want to backup my base using `pg_dump`, but (for various reasons) I want each table to have its own dumping file. I could do something like:

```
$ pg_dump -t table_a -f export_a.sql
$ pg_dump -t table_b -f export_b.sql
```

but consistency wouldn't be assured: modifications could happens between the two dumps, so my two dumps would represent differents states of the database, which is not consistent.

My question is: Is there any way to ensure these two dumps to be consistent (like, to be in the same transaction or something), or to tell `pg_dump` to output each table of a single dump in its own file?

I have tried to use `pg_dump -Fd -Z0`, but outputted `.dat` don't seem readable enough to separate information of each table.

Comment: What do you mean "don't seem readable enough to separate information of each table?".  The help for `-Fd` says "This will create a directory with one file for each table and blob being dumped,".  Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: You will need to do `pg_restore -l  -f <dir_name>` to get a plain text version of the Table of Contents(TOC) from `toc.dat`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I actually didn't understand how to use `toc.dat`. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/49454121/7031981 post's answer have been pretty useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that. I have two ideas:

- Use a single `directory` format `pg_dump` (`-F d`) of all the tables. True, there will be a single `toc.dat` with all the table metadata, but each table will be dumped to its own file.
- Use a single `pg_dump` in `directory` or `custom` format to get a consistent dump for all tables, and then create individual files from it with

  ```
  pg_restore -t table1 -f table1.sql all_tables.dmp
  ```

##### Further reading:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: Yeah. I think I'll go for the 2nd solution, as files seem easier to manipulate this way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `--verbose` option to pg_dump, and redirect **both** stdout and stderr to a file.

As tables finish dumping, you'll see something like this in the output:

```
pg_dump: finished item 7463 TABLE DATA mc_request
```

A bit of `bash` and `awk` lets you rename the `9999.dat` files to "table-named" files.  One problem, though, is when different schemas have same table name.